# Exponential family form of multinomial distribution

Tags: multinomial-distribution, exponential-family

I feel like this must be a duplicate, but I don't know the magic words to find the appropriate post...

The multinomial distribution is a member of the exponential family. I am used to seeing the "standard" formulation of the multinomial distribution as:

$$p(x|\pi) = \frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^m x_i!}\prod_{i=1}^m \pi_i^{x_i}$$

I have seen multiple sources express the multinomial, in the form of an exponential family member as:

$$p(x|\pi) = \exp \{\sum_{i=1}^m x_i \ln \pi_i \}$$

My question is, what happened to the multinomial coefficient $\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^m x_i!}$ ??? If I try to go from the exponential family formulation back to the standard form, I get:

$$p(x|\pi) = \prod_{i=1}^m \pi_i^{x_i}$$

From Kevin Murphy's book, it appears that this exponential formulation only holds for a single trial, in which case the multinomial coefficient is 1.

Comment: I corrected the term $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i!$ into $\prod_{i=1}^m x_i!$

Comment: For an example where the data-dependent term is not omitted, see "Example 2.4 The multinomial distribution" in the Statistical Modelling by Exponential Families book by Sundberg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exponential families are characterised by their densities, which are such that the interaction between the outcome $x$ of the random variable and the parameter $\theta$ occurs in an exponential scalar product, 
$$\exp\{T(\theta)^\text{T} S(x)\}$$
The other terms in the density are the normalising constant $C(\theta)=\exp\{-\psi(\theta)\}$ and a function of $x$, $h(x)$, which comes to complement the dominating measure $\text{d}\nu(x)$. But all that matters is the product $h(x)\text{d}\nu(x)$ which can be seen as a new measure $\text{d}\nu´(x)$.

So in the multinomial example, the term
$${n \choose x_1 \cdots x_m}=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^m x_i!}$$
can either be seen as $h(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ completing the counting measure [which qualifies as "standard" in your terms] on $$\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\in\mathbb{N}^m;\sum_{i=1}^m x_i=n\right\}$$ or as part of a new measure on that set.

Comment: So in other words, it is still there, but is often "ignored" by books and literature as they omit the $h()$ term ?

Comment: hmm, but is still doesn't explain why the coefficient n!∏mi=1xi! is omitted. @Xavier Bourret Sicotte have u found a satisfied explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Let

1. $Y_{i}$ be a random variable, $i=1\dots k$.
2. $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the number of trials.
3. $y_{i}\in \mathbb{N}$ be the number of $i$-th events in a sequence of $n$ trials.
4. $p_{i}\in [0,1]$ be the probability of the $i$-th event of each trial.

The probability mass function of multinomial distribution is

$\begin{equation}
\displaystyle P(Y_{1}=y_{1},\dots,Y_{k}=y_{k}) =\frac{n!}{y_{1}!\dots y_{k}!}p_{1}^{y_{1}}\dots p_{k}^{y_{k}},
\end{equation}$

with $\displaystyle\sum^{k}_{i=1}y_{i}=n$, and $\displaystyle\sum^{k}_{i=1}p_{i}=1$.

**Multinomial distribution is in the exponential family**

*Proof.*
$\begin{align}
\displaystyle P(Y_{1}=y_{1},\dots,Y_{k}=y_{k}) &=\frac{n!}{y_{1}!\dots y_{k}!}p_{1}^{y_{1}}\dots p_{k}^{y_{k}}\\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{y_{1}!\dots y_{k}!}\right)p_{1}^{x1}\dots p_{k}^{1-\sum_{i}^{k-1}y_{i}}\\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{y_{1}!\dots y_{k}!}\right)\exp\left[y_{1}\log p_{1}+\dots+\left(1-\sum_{i}^{k-1}y_{i}\right)\log p_{k}\right]\\
&=\left(\frac{n!}{y_{1}!\dots y_{k}!}\right)\exp\left[y_{1}\log \left(\frac{p_{1}}{p_{k}}\right)+\dots+y_{k-1}\log\left(\frac{p_{1}}{p_{k-1}}\right)+\log p_{k}\right]\\
&=b(y_{1},\dots ,y_{k})\exp\left[\eta^{T}T(y_{1},\dots ,y_{k})-a(\eta)\right]
\end{align}$

, where

$\begin{align}
\eta&= \begin{bmatrix}
\log(p_{1}/p_{k}) \\
\log(p_{2}/p_{k}) \\
\vdots\\
\log(p_{k-1}/p_{k})\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
T(y_{1},\dots ,y_{k})&= \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} \\
y_{2} \\
\vdots\\
y_{k}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
a(\eta)&=-\log p_{k}\\
b(y_{1},\dots ,y_{k})&=\frac{n!}{y_{1}!\dots y_{k}!}.
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build the softmax regression from scratch, and got stuck here also: why all the posts just silently omit the coefficient $\frac{n!}{x_1! x_2! \dots x_k!}$ totally, after some research and thinking i share my understanding here:

In reality, we always use a special form of the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with $k>2$ and $n=1$, that is [categorical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution), and since $n=1$, then the coefficient $\frac{n!}{x_1! x_2! \dots x_k!}$ of the multinomial distribution's [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) will be always all 1, that is why we can omit it, more details:

$$
\begin{cases}
  \text{class 1 is chosen: } \frac{1!}{1! \cdot 0! \cdot 0! \dots 0!} = 1 \\
  \text{class 2 is chosen: } \frac{1!}{0! \cdot 1! \cdot 0! \dots 0!} = 1 \\
  \text{class 3 is chosen: } \frac{1!}{0! \cdot 0! \cdot 1! \dots 0!} = 1 \\
  \vdots
\end{cases}
$$

For getting more details and a better full pic of understanding u can refer to my post [GLM and exponential family distributions -> Why the PMF has no coefficient](https://lnshi.github.io/ml-exercises/ml_basics_in_html/rdm008_GLM_and_exponential_family_distributions/GLM_and_exponential_family_distributions.html#Why-the-PMF-has-no-coefficient?)

Especially pay attention to understand what does the $x_i$ stand for in multinomial distribution from [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function)

Comment: Would you be better asking this as a new question since an answer cannot get an answer?

Comment: @mdewey It reads like an effort to answer the question.  It appears only to address a very special case of the question, though, so whether it is correct or useful may be for each reader to determine.

Comment: @mdewey i was trying to answer the question, not seeking any answer, since the accepted answer totally doesn't address the main concern of the question: `why the coefficient is silently omitted`, i just share my understanding to may help someone